# ./build/tools/caffe: No such file or directory

Tags: bash, python-2.7, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning

I have a question regarding the command for running the training in Linux. I am using GoogleNet model in caffe framework for binary classification of my images. I used the following command to train my dataset

./build/tools/caffe train --solver=models/MyModelGoogLenet/quick_solver.prototxt

But I received this error

bash: ./build/tools/caffe: No such file or directory

How can I resolve this error? Any suggestions would be of great help.

Comment: You don't have a `build/tools/caffe` file from your current directory.

Comment: Try changing that `./build/tools/caffe train` to an absolute path like `/home/user/build/tools/caffe train` or wherever it's sitting.

Comment: You will need to find where `caffe` is installed.  Do you have a sub-directory `build`?  Does the `build` sub-directory contain a directory `tools`?  Is there a file `build/tools/caffe`?  (The answer to the last is 'no'; the shell error message says as much.)  Why do you think `caffe` is in that directory?  Can you find where it is installed?  Did you install it?

Comment: Thanks a lot it solved my problem. From now on, I will use only absolute path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should specify absolute paths to all your files and commands, to be on the safer side. If `/home/user/build/tools/caffe train` still doesn't work, check if you have a `build directory` in your `caffe root`. If not, then use `/home/user/tools/caffe train` instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot it solved my problem. From now on, I will use only absolute path.

Answer (score 4):

Follow the below instructions and see if it works:

- Open a terminal
- `cd` to caffe root directory
- Make sure the file `caffe` exists by listing them using `ls ./build/tools`
- If the file is not present, type `make`. Running step 3 will list the file now.
- Type `./build/tools/caffe`, `No such file` error shouldn't get triggered this time.